# Equivalent of file_get_contents() with CURL?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get some JSON data from a url like this:

```
$url = 'http://site.com/search.php?term=search term here';
$result = json_decode ( file_get_contents($url) );
```

However the client's webhost has got the `allow_url_fopen` setting disabled, hence the code above doesn't work.

What's the equivalent code of the lines above? Basically, a search term needs to be submitted via `$_GET`to the url.

Comment: I protected this due to the number of nearly _identical_ answers. Folks, please consider up-voting an existing answer prior to adding another, especially if an existing answer covers the exact same ground that you want to cover. We now have five almost identical examples of how to fetch a URL using curl.

Comment: @Tim Post consider that a. everyone who has answered the question so far had >10 rep, and all answers so far were given within minutes after the question was asked. Therefore, I don't think protection is necessary. I'd have deleted my answer (I wasn't the first), but it seems to be the only one to include error handling, and is the highest-voted one as of writing this.

Comment: @phihag I was concerned that this would draw a lot more views than it did (due to spending quite a bit of time on the front page). Questions that draw a lot of duplicate answers also tend to draw a lot of flags, mostly due to new users trying to earn reputation. I was making sure the list didn't keep growing :) In any event, unprotected now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
$url = 'http://site.com/search.php?term=search term here';

$rCURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$aData = curl_exec($rCURL);

curl_close($rCURL);

$result = json_decode ( $aData );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
if ($jsonData === false) {
    throw new Exception('Can not download URL');
}
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($jsonData);
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need is here.

http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_curl

Basically, try something like this

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = json_decode($content);
    return $header;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you checked it out like this.?

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set parameters
$parameters = array(
    'foo'=>'bar',
    'herp'=>'derp'
);

// add get to url
$url = 'http://example.com/index.php'
$url.= '?'.http_build_query($parameters, null, '&');

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return the content

// execute
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

You should then have the file contents in $data, you'll probably want to do some error checking but you can find out how to do that at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php).