# Filling form field

Tags: php, curl

I want to fill a form field and submit it using CURL.The webpage has many form fields which are already filled so i do not want to touch these fields.

So is it possible to use curl and fill **only** the required field and submit it along with all other fields which are already filled ?

Comment: In order to get the pre-filled fields you'd first need to retrieve the remote page, parse the field values from the retrieved text and then merge those values with your final form submission curl request. Are you looking for help with how to make this happen or did you just want to know if it could be done? :)

Comment: @rdlowrey: this is what i was exactly looking for..do u know how could it be done?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the exact formatting of the remote page's HTML. If I were to answer how to do everything except pull out the pre-filled values, could you take it from there? If not, you'll have to supply the address to the specific page you need to scrape data from.

Comment: Give me few minutes i will upload html code into github and post the link here..

Comment: please find the html here : http://jnrntr.wordpress.com/

Comment: For the record, that's a terrible way to post html :) next time use pastebin.com or pastie.org. Walkthrough posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A full walkthrough (given the supplied HTML scrape text)

To customize you would simply add field names to the `$fields_i_want` array to specify all of the text field values you wanted to pull from the downloaded source text and change the URLs for retrieval and submission locations.

Also, a better alternative to `file_get_contents()` is curl. You can use the instructions on [**this SO post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349624/how-to-collect-html-source-response-from-a-remote-server/8349670#8349670) for how to retrieve remote text via curl.

```
// First, retrieve the remote source using file_get_contents()
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');    

$my_field_val  = 'my_field_value';
$fields_i_want = array('audien', 'unifor');
$field_vals    = array();
$field_string  = '';


// Use DOM to parse the values you want from the form
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);

// Get all the input field nodes
$inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');

// Iterate over the input fields and save the values we want to an array
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
  $name = $input->getAttribute('name');
  if (in_array($name, $fields_i_want)) {
    $val = $input->getAttribute('value');
    $field_vals[$name] = $val;
  }
}

// append the field value we set ourselves to the list
$field_vals['my_field'] = $my_field_val;

foreach ($field_vals as $key => $val) {
  $field_vals[$key] = urlencode($val)
}

// url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
  $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

// open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// POST the data to the form submission url
$submit_url = 'http://www.submitform.com';

// set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

// execute post (returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure)
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Everything worked well by following the walk through. But one of the field Description is not getting copied. Do you know why this can happen? This field has few lines of description and few symbols like <br> in it.

Comment: I just went through the html syntax ..its of type textarea could that be the problem?

Comment: is there a better way of just not limiting it to a type of just "input"?

Comment: $inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');

Comment: You could do it the same way as the example ... Add a line like `$tareas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('textarea');` and maybe compare its results to an array of textarea field names. Try to apply the concepts people have demonstrated and try to get smarter, don't just copy and paste other people's code! :)  If you try to make it work and have serious problems, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how the form is initially populated.

If the pre-populated elements all use `value="foo"` then just grab the page (using curl), load it up in to a DOMDocument, fetch the `<form>` you're after and populate the field(s) you need, then pass it off as another request using a new cURL request (taking in to account the form's `action` and `method` attributes, as well as form data being sent off).

However, if they're populated with JS and you don't plan on writing the cURL request to mimic what you're doing on your browser, I don't see an easy way of mimicking JS actions, then populating, then sending it off.

Also, this doesn't take in to account any cookies that may be present. If you need those, you're going to have to store them from the first request and make sure to send them off in the actual submission call.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it fits, but in order to check what are the required fields you need to parse the HTML and check for each input file and look for any required mention.

To parse the HTML, you can use some tools like:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

With that tools, you can open the page, look for any required tags on the fields, and then decide with form field to submit.

Comment: You are right Mike, actually, i think he can accomplish the task in a LOT of ways, but i feel that the question is not clear enough, probably that is what he is looking for.