# Save website sourecode to file via php

Tags: php, file, download, copy, translucency

Hi I wan to save the sourecode of http://stats.pingdom.com/w984f0uw0rey to some directory in my website

```
<?php
if(!copy("http://stats.pingdom.com/w984f0uw0rey", "stats.html"))
{
echo("failed to copy file");
}
;
?>
```

but this does not work either for me:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://stats.pingdom.com/w984f0uw0rey');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

But I cannot figure how to do it!

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to collect HTML source response from a remote server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349624/how-to-collect-html-source-response-from-a-remote-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
<?

file_put_contents('w984f0uw0rey.html', file_get_contents('http://stats.pingdom.com/w984f0uw0rey'));

?>
```

be sure that the script has write privileges to the current directory

Comment: you say `echo file_get_contents('http://....')` doesn't work. does it give you an error?

Comment: <?php $homepage = file_get_contents('http://stats.pingdom.com/qmwwuwoz2b71/522741';;); echo $homepage; ?> = Internal Server Error

Comment: I'm very confused by this. Is there everything OK with your server / apache settings / .htaccess file(s)?

Comment: I found the problem it was server side - thanks for your help it all worked great

Answer (score 1):

Use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: so like this? <?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://stats.pingdom.com/qmwwuwoz2b71/522741');
echo $homepage;
?>

Comment: @Chriswede: Yes, that will get the contents for you, then you need to store it, as Sorin has illustrated in the answer below mine.

Comment: Should be -1 for a FGITW one-liner answer with no explanation to an obviously confused newbie.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Except, I linked to the function spec, which has an very clearly defined example, that Chriswede was able to find. If someone is trying to do something like scrape a website and write to the file system, I don't think expecting them to read a man page is out of the realm of acceptable responses. Especially given how easy to read the PHP ones are...

Comment: @Josh but shouldn't <?php $homepage = file_get_contents('stats.pingdom.com/qmwwuwoz2b71/522741';); echo $homepage; ?> at least echo the source code of the site - but I am getting an server error: http://2jt.com/images/pw.php

Comment: @Chriswede: Are you supplying the `http://` part before your site? It won't just know the protocol without being told.

Comment: @Josh yes I am :  <?php $homepage = file_get_contents('http://stats.pingdom.com/qmwwuwoz2b71/522741';); echo $homepage; ?> -- server error

Answer (score 1):

The best variant you can do in PHP is to use [`stream_copy_to_stream`](http://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream):

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/file.zip';
$file = "/downloads/stats.html";
$src = fopen($url, 'r');
$dest = fopen($file, 'w');
echo stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest) . " bytes copied.\n";
```

If you need to add HTTP options like headers, use context options with the `fopen` call. See as well [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730392/367456) which shows how. It's likely you need to set a user-agent and things so that the other website's server believes you're a browser.

Comment: thanks but <?php

$url = 'http://stats.pingdom.com/w984f0uw0rey';
$file = "/file.html";
$src = fopen($url, 'r');
$dest = fopen($file, 'w');
echo stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest) . " bytes copied.\n";

?> did not work for me...

Comment: Actually I suggest you remove the `'` at the end of the URL. Otherwise it will give you the page not found page. Anyway it works, you don't even need additional HTTP context options.

Comment: sorry what do I need to remove? <?php

$url = 'http://stats.pingdom.com/w984f0uw0rey';$file = "/file.html";
$src = fopen($url, 'r');
$dest = fopen($file, 'w');
echo stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest) . " bytes copied.\n";

?>

Comment: Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9ruxKS (working, uses output not file because that codepad has no files).