# Curl timedout with this image

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to fetch this image using cURL: http://images.egypt.souq.com/media/item/2013/02/27/49/97/32/8/item_L_4997328_1650476.jpg

Using this code:

```
public static function fetchUrl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch); //get curl response
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

this code is working with any image (that I tried at least) except for the above image, it returns false after consuming all the timeout's 50 seconds,

did anybody know why?

Comment: Are the other images you have tried on the same domain as the one you posted?

Comment: It seems to happen with any images on that domain. With that in mind, I would assume they have something in place to stop people stealing their images / linking directly to their site in this way.

Comment: ya, I have tried other images on the same domain, and all give the same result, is there anyway to get those images?, or I just have to minimize the timeout and handle the false condition then?

Comment: That would seem like the only option in this case.

Comment: I tried wget in a terminal and it fetched the image, so is there any other way to fetch it through php other than cURL?

Comment: See my answer. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the userAgent for cURL solved my problem:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

here I'm getting the userAgent from the request,

or I can even specify it manually like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "spider");
```

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6595108/905801

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ez0-128).

```
<?php

function data_uri($file, $mime) 
{  
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  $base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
  return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
?>

<img src="<?php echo data_uri('http://images.egypt.souq.com/media/item/2013/02/27/49/97/32/8/item_L_4997328_1650476.jpg','image/jpg'); ?>" />
```

Information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070603/php-recreate-and-display-an-image-from-binary-data).

Comment: Your answer works fine, but file_get_contents isn't enabled on my server. I found the suitable solution for me by specifying the userAgent as in my answer. Anyway, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I don't think that HTTP wrappers will magically succeed where Curl fails. And what has the rest of the code have to do with the question?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - Regardless of the magic involved, his original code didn't work in phpFiddle and the example I have posted did. The `img` tag was a demonstration to show the image coming back. I guess the userAgent was the issue as he has posted so I assume `get_file_contents` deals with that "magically"

Comment: The [details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php): *If you have configured a [user_agent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent) string using your php.ini file or the stream context, it will also be included in the request.*